# Laravel 8 enable maintenance mode permanently

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using this command to enable maintenance mode `php artisan down --secret="1630542a-246b-4b66-afa1-dd72a4c43515`.

And then, I access my site with `exapmple.com/1630542a-246b-4b66-afa1-dd72a4c43515`, to bypass the maintenance mode.

However, it seems to only work for one browsing session. That is, when I restart the computer, the maintenance cookie seems to be deleted and my site shows the 503 error.

So, how can I set an infinity lifetime maintenance cookie?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Override Create method from MaintenanceModeBypassCookie class. For this we will create a new file /App/Http/MaintenanceModeByoassCookie.php where we will include the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class MaintenanceModeBypassCookie extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\MaintenanceModeBypassCookie
{
    /**
     * Create a new maintenance mode bypass cookie.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie
     */
    public static function create(string $key)
    {
        $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addHours(1000);//Time expiration for your cookie

        return new Cookie('laravel_maintenance', base64_encode(json_encode([
            'expires_at' => $expiresAt->getTimestamp(),
            'mac' => hash_hmac('sha256', $expiresAt->getTimestamp(), $key),
        ])), $expiresAt);
    }
}
```

Note where we are overriding the expiration time for the cookie.

**2.** Add the following code in your /App/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php in order to override bypassResponse method:

```
/**
     * @override
     * Redirect the user back to the root of the application with a maintenance mode bypass cookie.
     *
     * @param  string  $secret
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function bypassResponse(string $secret)
    {
        return redirect('/')->withCookie(
            \App\Http\MaintenanceModeBypassCookie::create($secret)
        );
    }
```